# How to return binary data from an API endpoint

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to return binary data from an endpoint using [Nuxt3 server endpoint](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#sending-streams-experimental),
the data size can be large most of the times (couple of megabytes)

my implementation returns invalid data, and I'm not sure what is missing in my implementation

```js
import { useS3 } from '#myApp/s3'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { client } = await useS3()
  const bucket = event.context.params.bucket
  const objectKey = getHeader(event, 'content-location')
  const filename = objectKey.split('/').pop()

  if (!objectKey) {
    throw createError({
      statusCode: 400,
      statusMessage: 'Object Key Not Defined',
      message: 'content-location header should include the object key',
    })
  }

  // set headers
  setHeader(event, 'content-disposition', `attachment; filename="${filename}"`)
  setHeader(event, 'Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')

  // begin stream
  const stream = await client.getObject(bucket, objectKey)
  const buffer = await ToBuffer(stream)
  return buffer
})

function ToBuffer(stream): Promise<Buffer> {
  const chunks = [] as Buffer[]
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stream.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk)))
    stream.on('error', (err) => reject(err))
    stream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)))
  })
}
```